# How to change text based on different drop down selections?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to have three drop down menus. When you make a certain combination of selections in the three menus, then text on the website should change  Ex. one drop down for size selections, color selections, and fruit selections. If you pick big, red, and apple, then there should be html text on the website that changes to Big red apple. So far I have only been able to accomplish this by selecting only one option in the drop down menu that generates the Big red apple text I am going for. I want to know how to make it so the text waits for three combination of options to transform. Any suggestions or advice? This is what I have so far -

> ```
>  <!DOCTYPE html>
>  <html>
>   <body>
>
>  Select your favorite fruit:
>  <select name = "size" onchange="test(this);">
>  <option value = "small"> small </option>
>  <option value = "medium"> medium </option>
>  <option value = "large"> large </option>
>  </select>
>
>  Select your favorite fruit:
>  <select name = "colors" onchange="test(this);">
>  <option value = "red"> red </option>
>  <option value = "blue"> blue </option>
>  <option value = "green"> green </option>
>  </select>
>
>  Select your favorite fruit:
>  <select name = "fruit" onchange="test(this);">
>  <option value = "apple">apple</option>
>  <option value = "pineapple">pineapple</option>
>  <option value = "banana">banana</option>
>  </select>
>
>  <p id="text">Hello World!</p>
>
>
>    <script>
>    function myFunction(name)
>    {
>    document.getElementById("peep").innerHTML = "Welcome " + name;
>    }
>    </script>
>
>
>    <script>
>    window.test = function(e){
>     var red1 = "red" && "Day";
>
>    if(e.value=="large" && "red" && "apple"){
>        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Large red apple"
>    }
>    else if(e.value=="small" && "green" && "banana"){
>        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Small green  
>      banana";       
>     }
>    else if(e.value == "medium" && "yellow" && "pineapple"){
>        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Medium yellow pinepple";
> }
> }
> </script>
>
>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a native javascript solution:

The idea is to save the each of the users choice in a variable outside the function, then you can implement your logic:

```
<script>
size = ''
color = ''
fruit = ''
window.test = function(e){
   if (e.value == 'red' || e.value == 'blue' || e.value == 'green'){
     color = e.value
   }
   if (e.value == 'apple' || e.value == 'pineapple' || e.value == 'banana'){
     fruit = e.value
   }
   if (e.value == 'small' || e.value == 'medium' || e.value == 'large'){
     size = e.value
   }

   if (size == 'large' && fruit == 'apple' && color == 'red'){
     document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Large red apple"
   }
} 
</script>
```

Comment: I can see what you are approaching idea wise, but they were asking how to make the text display only when all 3 select tags have been changed.  Your fourth if statement would remove the dynamic nature of what it seems like the asker is trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

Each time a select control is changed, you can check all three select controls to see if any remain at their defaults. If not, then you can update the `#text` field.

Alternately, you can use a variable. Set it initially to zero, and increment by one each time a select is changed. If the variable value is > 2, you can update the `#text` field.

Example:

```js
$('select').change(function(){
   var s1 = $('#size').val();
   var s2 = $('#colors').val();
   var s3 = $('#fruit').val();
   
   if (s1 != '' && s2 != '' && s3 != ''){
     $('#text').text(s1 +' '+ s2 +' '+ s3);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

 Select your favorite fruit:
 <select id="size" name = "size">
 <option value = ""> Choose </option>
 <option value = "small"> small </option>
 <option value = "medium"> medium </option>
 <option value = "large"> large </option>
 </select>

 Select your favorite fruit:
 <select id="colors" name = "colors">
 <option value = ""> Choose </option>
 <option value = "red"> red </option>
 <option value = "blue"> blue </option>
 <option value = "green"> green </option>
 </select>

 Select your favorite fruit:
 <select id="fruit" name = "fruit">
 <option value = ""> Choose </option>
 <option value = "apple">apple</option>
 <option value = "pineapple">pineapple</option>
 <option value = "banana">banana</option>
 </select>

 <p id="text">Hello World!</p>
```

Comment: This method also works.  It uses JQuery to simplify your code much more than `document.getElementById()`

Comment: Based on the method shown in the javascript above, you would just need to decide what font point you want represented by each named size. For example, small could be mapped to a class ".small { font-size: 10px }" medium could be ".medium { font-size: 12px }" and large could be ".large { font-size: 14px }". Then you could just use addClass(s1) from the var assignment shown. If you were going to apply this to all text on a page (not sure why; perhaps this is your homework?) you could simply use body.addClass(s1).

Answer (score -1):

Each of your `<select>` tags should have an additional `<option>` tag as the first child, that stores a default value.  Example:

```
<select onchange="test(this)">
  <option>...</option>
  <option>Option1</option>
  <option>Option2</option>
  <option>Options3</option>
</select>
```

The next step involves altering your test function:

```
window.test = function(e){
   if(document.getElementsByName("size")[0].value != "..." && document.getElementsByName("colors")[0].value != "..." && document.getElementsByName("fruit")[0].value != "..."){
     var red1 = "red" && "Day";

     if(e.value=="large" && "red" && "apple"){
         document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Large red apple"
     }
     else if(e.value=="small" && "green" && "banana"){
         document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Small green  
     banana";       
     }
     else if(e.value == "medium" && "yellow" && "pineapple"){
         document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = "Medium yellow pinepple";
     }
  }
}
```

The added if statement will check if the user has selected an option from each select tag.

For additional help:
Select Tag DOM:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_value.asp

or you can try the multiple method for creating one drop down box

Multiple:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_multiple.asp

EDIT:
Here is how I would go about it:

```
    <select id = "select1" onchange="test(this)">
      <option>...</option>
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
      <option>Options3</option>
    </select>
    <select id = "select2" onchange="test(this)">
      <option>...</option>
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
      <option>Options3</option>
    </select>
    <select id = "select3" onchange="test(this)">
      <option>...</option>
      <option>Option1</option>
      <option>Option2</option>
      <option>Options3</option>
    </select>
    <span id = "finalResult"></span>

var test = function(){
  //grab all the values
  var s1 = document.getElementById("select1").value;
  var s2 = document.getElementById("select2").value;
  var s3 = document.getElementById("select3").value;
  //debug
  console.log(s1 + ", " + s2 + ", " + s3);
  //check to make sure every value is set
  if(s1 != "..." && s2 != "..." && s3 != "..."){
    //set the final string
    document.getElementById("finalResult").innerHTML = s1 + " " + s2 + " " + s3;
  }
}
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pixelknight1398/3u95pusb/)

Comment: Hey thank you for your response. I added your code and tried messing with it but it doesn't seem to change the results when I make selections. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try giving each select element an id, and use `document.getElementById()` instead of `document.getElementsByName()`  Also when the page loads: `<body onload = "myFunction()">` in `myFunction()` check the values of each select and make sure that they are default to "..." instead of `undefined` or `null`.  Otherwise you will end up with errors.

Comment: check my edit.  you can also use the jquery that is in the other answer